# Blender 2.8 Subdivision Surface on planes not sharp with creases

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface

In Blender 2.79, creasing the corner of a subdivided plane generates the expected sharp corner:
[image: Blender 2.79 plane with solidify]

When using Blender 2.8, I can't replicate this behavior without triangulating the face and creasing the third edge to the corner.

[image: Blender 2.8 planes with solidify]

Adding a solidify modifier and creasing the rim sharpens the corner, but I don't always want to solidify the geometry.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that this is currently an open bug in 2.8 according to this link: [Blender Bug Tracker - Round corner in edge crease of subdivided surfaces](https://developer.blender.org/T58640)